# Prove that this is a partial order

Tags: relations, order-theory

I am reading Charles Pinter's "Set Theory" and I found an exercise which I can't resolve. Maybe someone can help me. It says:

> We will consider pairs $(B,G)$ where $B \subseteq A$, and $G$ is an order relation in $B$ which well-orders $B$. Let $A^*$ be the family of all such pairs $(B,G)$. We introduce the symbol $<$ and define $(B,G) < (B',G')$ if and only if:
>   a) $B \subset B'$
>   b) $G \subset G'$
>   c) $x \in B, y \in B' \setminus B \implies (x,y) \in G'$.
>   Verify that $<$ is a partial order relation in $A^*$.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What have you tried, that you couldn't pass? Could you verify that the order is reflexive? Could you verify it is antisymmetric? Could you verify it is transitive? What tripped you in the places that you couldn't?

Comment: I think I verified that its reflexive. But honestly i have no idea of how to start to verify the antisymmetric and transitive property.

Comment: Well, check that against the definitions. Suppose $(B,G)<(B',G')$ and $(B',G')<(B,G)$ and conclude that $B=B'$ and $G=G'$.

Comment: so, I can just suppose the two above mentioned cases without a problem? ok. so with this I have the antisymmetric property. And for the transitive?

Comment: Again, verify against the definition of transitivity. One step at a time, and you can't lose.

Comment: i have to verify that if (B,G)<(B',G') and (B',G')<(B'',G'') then (B,G)<(B'',G'') right?

Comment: That's right. The ordering $(B,G) < (B',G')$ says that $(B,G)$ is an initial segment of $(B',G')$ — that is, the latter is an end extension of the former. $G$ and $G'$ agree on $B$, and any new elements in $B'$ come after (with respect to $G'$) all elements in $B$.

Comment: ok thanks a lot. I think I got it now